# How do you stub a method in mockito for dart?

Tags: dart, mockito

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

class Cat {
  bool meow() {
    return true;
  }
}

class MockCat extends Mock implements Cat {}

void main() {
  Cat mockCat = MockCat();
  test('Mockito', () {
    when(mockCat.meow()).thenReturn(true);
    expect(mockCat.meow(), true);
  });
}
```

Hi,

I am learning how to use mockito ^5.0.2 in Dart.
But anything I seem to do, doesn't work.

Here is the debug output for the above line codes :

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
MockCat.meow
test\…\use_cases\mockito_test.dart:5
main.<fn>
test\…\use_cases\mockito_test.dart:15
2

✖ Mockito
Exited (1)
```

Do you get the same output with the same code ?
What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: As explained in the [mockito documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito), you will need to add a code generation step to use Mockito with Dart 2.12 and null-safety enabled.  See https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/NULL_SAFETY_README.md for details.

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thank you.